# Value in a java bean to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, javabeans

Im incredibly stuck creating this. The idea of my program is to play who want to be a millionaire and each bean is each question. I am instructing the servlet to read the bean and send the question and possible answers to the JSP to be displayed. the user will then choose one of the answers via hyperlink which places a query string into the url for the servlet to check the chosen answer to the actual answer.

I also would like to make the point I am very new at this I know my servlet is wrong i just dont understand how to do it :P thank you everyone who takes the time to take a look at this!

Here is the JSP:

```
<html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Millionaire.css">


    <body>
    <form method="get">
        <img src="img/mlogo.jpg" >

        <table>
        <th> Question: </th>
        <th>${Bean.Question}</th>
        </table>

        <br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=a">A: ${Bean.question} </a></td>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=b">B: ${Bean.a2} </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=c">C: ${Bean.a3} </a></td>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=d">D: ${Bean.a4} </a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br>

        <table>
        <th> Life-Lines </th>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="?selectedLifeLine=1">Skip</a></td>
            <td><a href="?selectedLifeLine=2">Skip</a></td>
            <td><a href="?selectedLifeLine=3">Skip</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div><input type="submit" value="Final Answer"><div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Servlet:

package assignment1;

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import assignment1.question1;
/**
 *
 * @author Powa
 */
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response)
                   throws IOException, ServletException{

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        question1.getAttribute("question");

        session.setAttribute("Bean","Question");

        session.setAttribute("Bean","a1");
        session.setAttribute("Bean","a2");
        session.setAttribute("Bean","a3");
        session.setAttribute("Bean","a4");



    }
}
```

And finally here is the bean for the first question:

package assignment1;

```
/**
 *
 * @author Powa
 */
public class question1 implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String question = "What type of Pokemon is Pikachu?";
    private String a1 = "Fire";
    private String a2 = "Water";
    private String a3 = "Grass";
    private String a4 = "Electric";

    private String answer = "Electric";

    /**
     * @return the question
     */
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    /**
     * @param question the question to set
     */
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    /**
     * @return the a1
     */
    public String getA1() {
        return a1;
    }

    /**
     * @param a1 the a1 to set
     */
    public void setA1(String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the a2
     */
    public String getA2() {
        return a2;
    }

    /**
     * @param a2 the a2 to set
     */
    public void setA2(String a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the a3
     */
    public String getA3() {
        return a3;
    }

    /**
     * @param a3 the a3 to set
     */
    public void setA3(String a3) {
        this.a3 = a3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the a4
     */
    public String getA4() {
        return a4;
    }

    /**
     * @param a4 the a4 to set
     */
    public void setA4(String a4) {
        this.a4 = a4;
    }

    /**
     * @return the answer
     */
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    /**
     * @param answer the answer to set
     */
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the key as "Bean" for a1,a2,a3,a4. It is overriding the previous values. try to give different attribute names. Also, a1,a2.. values are passed as strings. If you want the values in question1 class, instantiate question1 and do something like session.setAttribute("a1",question1.getA1());

Comment: When i use the session.getAttrbute like you said i get an error saying that "non-static method getA1() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

First step,modify you servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("question1",new question1());
```

and modify you jsp like this:

```
<html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Millionaire.css">


    <body>
    <form method="get">
        <img src="img/mlogo.jpg" >

        <table>
        <th> Question: </th>
        <th>${sessionScope.question1.question}</th>
        </table>

        <br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=a">A: ${sessionScope.question1.a1} </a></td>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=b">B: ${sessionScope.question1.a2} </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=c">C: ${sessionScope.question1.a3} </a></td>
                <td><a href="?selectedAnswer=d">D: ${sessionScope.question1.a4} </a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br>

        <table>
        <th> Life-Lines </th>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="?selectedLifeLine=1">Skip</a></td>
            <td><a href="?selectedLifeLine=2">Skip</a></td>
            <td><a href="?selectedLifeLine=3">Skip</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div><input type="submit" value="Final Answer"><div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately the values still do not display in my jsp